# Why does a "better" Schottky diode result in inferior AC-DC converter performance?

Tags: ac-dc, schottky

I have an AC-DC converter that outputs 6 A current at 12 V output. It's based on the CR6850 PWM controller. The schematic diagram is attached.

I need to increase the output current to 10 A. The high voltage side doesn't have any problems handling it. The problem is Schottky diode D8 (on low voltage side) which starts heating up too much under 10 A current. The diode is model MBR20200.

My idea was to replace that diode with another Schottky diode that has lower forward voltage drop. According to the datasheet, the MBR20200 has 0.8 V drop at 10 A current. I found plenty of similar diodes with much lower voltage drop (within 0.3-0.4 V under the same 10 A current.) When I replaced the MBR20200 I got the following results:

1. MBR2535CTLG - the converter fails to start
2. MBR40L45CT - works, but heats up much more
3. FERD30M45CT - the converter fails to start
4. MBR40250TG - works, but heats up much more

Looking at the datasheets I can't find anything substantially different that may make the AC-DC converter completely stop operating.

Why do these diodes not only fail to improve the operation, but even make it much worse?

[image: CR6850]

Comment: What are the other component types/ratings? What is T2's winding diagram, or parameters (especially inductances)? Have you taken any oscilloscope waveforms, especially of Q1 D and S, D8 anode?

Comment: Larger diodes have more capacitance. So if you didn't adjust the snubber components, there could be more ringing in the circuit that causes the excess dissipation or malfunction altogether.

Comment: Other components are fine, I tested the same circuit under 10A load with fan mounted on D8 and it works just fine. @TimWilliams

Comment: @tobalt yes that makes a lot of sense, so do you propose to adjust R6-C6 snubber? How can I calculate its values? Thanks

Comment: Also the MBR40L45CT can have 275 mA of reverse leakage when it gets hot.  Probably doesn't help.   120 W is a lot for a flyback, maybe consider a different topology if possible.

Comment: @JohnD agree and I would switch to another topology, but the problem is that we have a bunch of those power supplies stocked that claim 10A current and provide only 6A. So I was tasked to fix all of those )

Comment: What heatsink are you using for D8?

Comment: @Andyaka it's an ordinary aluminum heatsink with 8 fins, about 80 cm2 total surface  area

Comment: @Isso you need to check it out as per my guidance (not an answer necessarily).

Comment: (You might edit the question to mention 10 A is the rated current and 6 A the unacceptable observed performance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I spent quite a bit of time trying various approaches to solve this issue and I finally found two Schottky diode models that perform better than the MBR20200CT that the power adapter came with. Those diode models are:

1. NTSJ30U100CTG - 50% less heat generation!
2. MBR30100FCT - 25% less heat generation.

Basically the first diode model allows me to increase the output to 10A and solve this issue. I set it to 9A to be on the safe side, so far the tests seem to be passing well.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse leakage will kill that diode anyway, it'll be getting progressively hotter unless heatsinked very well. Even then it's a long shot. Paralleling them doesn't work unless they are very well thermally coupled, due to current hogging.

The "replacement" for that diode is either a well designed parallel combination, taking into account junction capacitance and reverse leakage of the combo, or a synchronous rectifier, or a different topology of a power supply altogether.

But then, how do you even know that the transformer T2, or Q1, or other components will survive continuous operation without problems. How close is T2 to saturation?

The idea that these supplies can be easily fixed in a real product is IMHO fiction. You'll have to basically reverse-engineer their design and fully validate the design with your fix. At that point you're designing your own power supply, except using someone else's sub-par design. It will cost much more than just buying proper power supplies. How well will this hack work when the environment is at the upper rated temperature? I mean, your product isn't sold to operate in 20C+/-5C, right?

Also, whenever you buy a lot of supplies from a new vendor: at least randomly and uniformly select a few, and test!

Answer (score 1):

**In the event that you miscalculated your heatsink requirements, here's my estimate.**

From [Wikipedia - TO-220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TO-220#:%7E:text=Further%20increase%20of%20heat%20dissipation,approximately%2070%20%C2%B0C%2FW.): -

> When a TO-220 package is used without a heatsink, the package acts as
> its own heatsink, and the heatsink-to-ambient thermal resistance in
> air for a TO-220 package is approximately 70 °C/W.

At 8 amps and a forward drop of 0.8 volts, the power might be about 6.4 watts and, a heatsink is definitely necessary. However, as it warms the forward volt-drop will lower to maybe 0.65 volts or a power or 5.2 watts.

Assuming 5.2 watts, and using the figure from wiki, a heatsink of 10 °C/watt (added to the junction-to-case and the case-to-heatsink thermal resistance of 2.5 °C/watt) yields an overall thermal resistance of 12.5 °C/watt.

So, with 5.2 watts being dissipated, the temperature rise of the junction will be 65 °C. In an ambient of 25 °C the junction might reach 90 °C. But, due to local ambient rises around the heatsink (due to warming the surrounding air) the junction might reach 100 °C or more.

So, that's pretty hot and you say the heatsink fitted is 80 cm2 total surface area.

You should double check the heatsink using my calculations as a template. I'm not saying your heatsink is the weak-point but, I am saying you nrrd to check this out properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have a flyback converter. When the switch is on for accumulating the magnetic field energy to the transformer core there's a substantial reverse voltage pulse on the secondary. During that period the transformer works as a normal transformer. I guess it's voltage is too high at least for those diodes which stall your converter operation. Calculate or preferably measure! We cannot do it, we know nothing of the transformer winding ratio.

Overheating without proper cooling at high output current is explained already by others.

Comment: The peak reverse voltage of the diode is 200 volts FYI. It would have to be a step down ratio that is less than 1:2 for this to happen. Not saying it isn't of course.